# Insert multiple values in database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert multiple values in my database. But I could not find the Solution to do what I want.

My problem here is that I have a array of values like 
`("6.40","6.50","7.00","7.10","7.20","7.30")`
and I want to insert these values in each row like 6.40 will store in one row corresponding of id "1".

Similarly "6.50" will store in id of "2". The id will just auto increment.

Similarly it will insert values in database until array empty. If anyone has any ideas on how to solve this problem please help me out! Please bear my doubts. I am new to PHP. Thanks in advance.

```
 for ($i=0;$i < count($slot_timings1); $i++)
 { 
    $q = $this->link->prepare('INSERT INTO doctor_appointment (doctor_name,doctor_id,appointment_date,slot_name,slot_timings) VALUES (:doctor_name,:doctor_id,:appointment_date,:slot_name,slot_timings)');
    $q->execute(array(':doctor_name'=>$doctor_name,':doctor_id'=>$doctor_id, ':appointment_date'=>$appointment_date,':slot_name'=>$slot_name,':slot_timings'=‌​>$slot_timings));
 } 
 $counts = $q->rowCount(); 
 return $counts;
```

Comment: Post the query you are using to insert.

Comment: use foreach or for loop for multiple insert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does 'foreach' actually work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-foreach-actually-work)

Comment: Without `foreach` it can be done I guess.

Comment: if u do with for each or for loop ... it effects ur site performance  :) use single query for  multiple insertion

Comment: @KavyaShree Add the code to the question.

Comment: Ya i tried with foreach but it insert only single value

Comment: You are passing the same values in every loop.

Comment: should be `$slot_timings[$i]`

Comment: What do u mean @Sougata

Comment: for ($i=0;$slot_timings[$i]; $i++) if this is correct or not

Comment: no.. in your `insert statement` not in your `for loop` .

Comment: in insert query replace `,slot_timings` with `,:slot_timings`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
foreach($slot_timings1 as $data)
     { 
        $q = $this->link->prepare('INSERT INTO doctor_appointment (doctor_name,doctor_id,appointment_date,slot_name,slot_timings) VALUES (:doctor_name,:doctor_id,:appointment_date,:slot_name,slot_timings)');
        $q->execute(array(':doctor_name'=>$doctor_name,':doctor_id'=>$doctor_id, ':appointment_date'=>$appointment_date,':slot_name'=>$slot_name,':slot_timings'=‌​>$data));
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if(is_array($slot_timings1) && !empty($slot_timings1))
{
 foreach ($slot_timings1 as $slot_timing)
 { 
$q = $this->link->prepare('INSERT INTO doctor_appointment (doctor_name,doctor_id,appointment_date,slot_name,slot_timings) VALUES (:doctor_name,:doctor_id,:appointment_date,:slot_name,:slot_timings)');

 $q->execute(array(':doctor_name'=>$doctor_name,':doctor_id'=>$doctor_id, ':appointment_date'=>$appointment_date,':slot_name'=>$slot_name,':slot_timings'=>$slot_timing));
} 

return count($slot_timings1);    
}
```

Comment: After using this it is showing "number of bound variables does not match number of tokens" error. i dont know whts d problem

Comment: can you show us the output for print_r($slot_timings1); ?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 6.10
    [1] => 6.30
    [2] => 6.40
)

Comment: Thank u so much @Er Faiyaz Alam

Comment: I have one more doubt is it possible to specify the position where i can insert this array of values.example insert should take place from the position of id="25"

Comment: @KavyaShree yes it is possible. for this you have to use on more sql field 'id'  for first time inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107628/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-faiyaz-alam).

Answer (score 1):

```
if(is_array($slot_timings1)){


 sort($slot_timings1); //Sort the elements of the array in ascending

$sql = "INSERT INTO doctor_appointment (doctor_name,doctor_id,appointment_date,slot_name,slot_timings) VALUES ";

$query_val = array();
foreach($slot_timings1 as $gettime){

    $row1 = $doctor_name;
    $row2 = $doctor_id;
    $row3 = $appointment_date;
    $row4 = $slot_name;
    $row5 = $gettime;
    $query_val[] = "('$row1', '$row2', '$row3', '$row4', '$row5')";
}

$sql .= implode(',', $query_val);

mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); 
}
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '$valuesArr' (T_VARIABLE)..other and all  okay but in case of valuesArr[] it is showing error

Comment: Ya i find the mistake. u forgt to mention one semicolon but what the problem is im using PHP pdo..bt the code u specified in mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for ($i=0;$i < count($slot_timings1); $i++)
 { 
$q = $this->link->prepare('INSERT INTO doctor_appointment (doctor_name,doctor_id,appointment_date,slot_name,slot_timings) VALUES (:doctor_name,:doctor_id,:appointment_date,:slot_name,slot_timings)');
 $q->execute(array(':doctor_name'=>$doctor_name,':doctor_id'=>$doctor_id, ':appointment_date'=>$appointment_date,':slot_name'=>$slot_name,':slot_timings'=‌​>$slot_timings1[$i]));
} 
$counts = $q->rowCount(); 
return $counts;
```

Comment: If i declare $slot_timings1[$i] it is showing error.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' is the error im getting after used this

Comment: try @Insomania solution. Its better using foreach. I am having some trouble with debugging right now.